# Importar archivo pfx a Openvas

Tags: linux, seguridad

Estoy utilizando recientemente Openvas junto con AppScan de IBM para realizar pruebas de vulnerabilidad a aplicaciones con https.

Estas aplicaciones tienen un mutual authentication, donde primero se valida el certificado en un ESB y posteriormente, se manda la petición hacia el LDAP e Edirectory.

Quería saber cómo importar mi .pfx para poder hacer el scan con mutual authentication.

Comment: Hi. spanish is the official language for this site. please translate the question, if not it could be close.

Comment: Realiza tu pregunta en base a [ask].

Comment: @Jorgesys ya que tienes el superpoder mod, ¡sería práctico que cerraras inmediatamente estas preguntas en inglés!

Comment: Por curiosidad: ¿por qué redactaste la pregunta en inglés? ¿Llegaste desde [so] o accediste directamente a [es.so]? Nos encontramos con este caso diariamente y nos sería muy útil saber el motivo de la confusión, para poder mostrar la información de manera más clara y explicitar que este es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas en castellano.

Comment: Una disculpa, creí que había que redactar en inglés, pero ya lo modifiqué. Gracias.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario @gvv90. El tema es que estamos teniendo muchas preguntas en inglés y estamos intentando mejorar esto... Si se te ocurre qué fue lo que no estaba tan claro entre la diferencia entre [es.so] y [so], o cómo es que llegaste al sitio, nos interesa saber los motivos.